# jqGrid with navbar/pager having a custom function bound to the edit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using the jQuery plugin that generates interactive [tables called jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

I want to use this "[editfunc](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator&s%5B%5D=editfunc)" (2/3rds or 3/4ths down the page) but I can't find a clear example of how to implement it anywhere. I've attempted several differnt things and all of them leave me with total failure.

To be clear, the table generated looks something like this:

[image]

That lower bar is called the "navpbar" or "pager", you implement it as a separate DIV, the API and documentation is fairly unclear (to myself anyway) on how exactly I put a custom function onto those buttons such as "add", "edit", "delete", etc... I can get default functionality working, but I can't find anything through websearches, this site, or the API docs on what the actual implementation looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jqGrid has opened source. It helps to clear all questions directly in the code. Look at [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L1742-1756) for example. You will see what `navGrid` do on click on the 'Edit' button of the navigator:

```
var sr = $t.p.selrow;
if (sr) {
    if($.isFunction( o.editfunc ) ) {
        o.editfunc(sr);
    } else {
        $($t).jqGrid("editGridRow",sr,pEdit);
    }
} else {
    $.jgrid.viewModal("#"+alertIDs.themodal,{gbox:"#gbox_"+$t.p.id,jqm:true});
    $("#jqg_alrt").focus();
}
```

So if you define `editfunc` callback function the function will be called with id of selected row as the parameter instead of creating editing dialog by [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow).

The method [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) have many customization functionality. The `prmEdit` parameter of the [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) allow to specify any option used by [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow).

If you don't want do display editing form and display any other GUI instead you can use `editfunc` callback function. For example:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
    editfunc: function (rowid) {
        alert('The "Edit" button was clicked with rowid=' + rowid);
    }
});
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/editfunc.htm). Select a row and click on the "Edit" button and you will see the `alert` instead of the standard editing form.

Comment: I could have sworn that's precisely what I did. I won't be back to my desk until Monday and I'll let you know how this worked out.

Comment: @Incognito: OK, but how you can see, my demo works. So I suppose you do used it in some another way. Best regards.